# Regarding question about function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I was reading about function pointer. That it contains address of instructions. And there I encountered one question to find an element in array using function pointer. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return (*(int*)a == *(int*)b);
}

int search(void* arr, int arr_size, int ele_size, void* x, bool compare(const void*, const void*))
{
    char* ptr = (char*)arr; // Here why not int *ptr = (int*)arr;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        if (compare(ptr + i * ele_size, x))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 5, 7, 90, 70 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int x = 7;
    printf("Returned index is %d ", search(arr, n, sizeof(int), &x, compare));
    return 0;
}
```

In the search function `char *ptr  = (char*)arr;` is used which is giving perfect answer =  `2`.
But when I have used `int *ptr  = (int*)arr;` it gives `-1` as answer.
Why is this? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is the smallest addressable unit in any C program, and on most system it corresponds to a single byte. That treats the array as a generic sequence of bytes, and uses the `ele_size` to calculate the byte-position of each element with `ptr + i*ele_size`.

If you use `int *ptr` then the byte-position calculation will be wrong by a factor of `sizeof(int)` (typically `4`), since the pointer arithmetic will be done in units of the base type (`int` instead of `char`).

Comment: But what's problem with int* ?

Comment: `char` corresponds to a byte [by defintion](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types). A byte is not necessarily an *octet*, i.e. 8 bits. There are machines that don't have an addressing mode that lets you grab only 8 bits at a time.

Comment: "But what's problem with int* ?" Please read the whole thing before asking.

Comment: The problem is that it points at an integer type.  Please read the answer before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

The function `search` knows nothing about what is the type of elements of the array pointed to by the pointer `arr` of the type `void *`.

So casting the pointer to the type `int *` does not make a sense.  If to do so then the expression `ptr + i*ele_size` where the pointer arithmetic is used will produce an incorrect result.

Comment: So basically we can't perform pointer arithmetic on pointer variable other than char, who points to any void type pointer.

Comment: @Hashinclude We can not use the expression  ptr + i*ele_size with a pointer to any other type except char, signed char or unsigned char.

Comment: Any reason behind that ?

Comment: @Hashinclude Because for a pointer for example of the type int * the expression i *ele_size will not be an index of the i-th element of the array.

Comment: For example: let suppose base address inside int* ptr is 2000. Since it's an array next element would be at 2004 for i = 1 expression would be (2000+1*4) which is equivalent to 2004 and so on? Is this evaluation wrong?

Comment: @Hashinclude The value of the pointer after evaluation of this expression  ptr + i * ele_size will be incremented by i * ele_size * sizeof( int )

Comment: Thank's man I got it. I was missing a small concept of pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

> That it contains address *of instructions*

There is a subtle difference between normal (object) pointers and function pointers. It is not possible to access the single instructions of a function - they do not have the same length.

With other pointers the increment (arithmetic) is adapted to the type, whether as `p[i]` or `p + i` or `*(p+i)`.

Side note: there still is `int` at the bottom of the call chain:

```
return (*(int*)a == *(int*)b);
```